# Spring Security not serving static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to get spring security to allow the serving of static files like .css .js etc. without need to login first.

I've tried creating MVC config with resource handler and changing rules in spring security config, but nothing seems to be working.

MvcConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/assets/");
}

}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/assets/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
}

}
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/assets/js/particles.min.js I'm expecting it to return the file contents but every time I try links like localhost:8080/assets/* it returns the content of login.html

[My assets files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvi5C.png)
[My project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHCAK.png)

Comment: I'm using 2.1.5, and I added @Configuration to code, but the issue persists

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/dVAg1WSW) This project is newly created this morning I was struggling to get that issue fixed for quite some time and I only have two more files I included a link to their contents but I don't think they will be helpful. This is my first project in which I use spring security so it's possible that somewhere I've made some simple error that I can not see. I also updated the post with screenshot of my files.

Comment: It is in subpackage config.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realized what happened I happen to refresh page same time it stopped at the breakpoint, and I assumed it was per request. Just check that again and you right it is once at the start.

Comment: Nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your static files are under `src/main/resources`:

[image]

There are two main pieces to configure:

Implement the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface to *discover* your static resources:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/assets/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/assets/");
        }
    }
}
```

Setup your security configuration to allow static resources (such as CSS, JavaScripts and images) to be publicly accessible:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  // Your settings

    @Override  
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Your AuthN handlers and filter chain...

        http        
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Logout handler...
    }
}
```

Supposing that you have a CSS file as follows:

`src/main/resources/assets/css/layout.css`

The web server will make it accessible at:

`http://<root_url>:<port>/css/layout.css`

Comment: The effect is the same it shows the content of login.html

Comment: Thus, the problem is somewhere else, since the static resource configuration is pretty straightforward. Did you check that your MVC controller is rendering the right content page? Are there any redirection managed by custom handlers?

Comment: There is only one controller with one mapping to handle /login i cant think of any other place where could be an issue other than security config

Comment: You get basically redirected by the authN filter chain. Take into account that if you put your static files is `src/main/resources/assets`, there is no need to include *"assets"* in your url. For instance, `src/main/resources/assets/css/layout.css` will be accessible at `http://<root_url>/css/layout.css` through the webserver.

Comment: The problem i ran into using this approach is, i cannot separate the access to static and access to controllers in my logging setup. my log files are being crowded with bunch of get requests to static files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/assets/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
```

Comment: Still, instead of file displays the content of login.html

Answer (score -1):

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
```

The statement above will tell spring security to Ignore any request that starts with *“/assets/”*. So if i were you, i will remove all the following configuration:

```
.antMatchers("/", "/assets/**")
        .permitAll()
```

fom the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.

Comment: I found that adding web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/") fixed issue for someone but even removing it doesn't fix the problem. Issue still persists

Comment: I think that you got me wrong. Look at this link https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/  to better understand